# replace divide by shift

Tags: c++, assembly

I am taking a look at following two small functions:

```
int foo(int val) {
  return val / 2;
}

int bar(int val) {
  return val >> 1;
}
```

I expected compiler to generate the same code for both of them. However, here is the generated assembly at O3

```
foo(int): # @foo(int)
 mov eax, edi
 shr eax, 31
 lea eax, [rax + rdi]
 sar eax
 ret
bar(int): # @bar(int)
 sar edi
 mov eax, edi
 ret
```

Here is the godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/g/XrtdEY

I was wondering why there is difference between these two assemblies.

Comment: It's because your numbers are signed. Make them `unsigned`, and assembly will be same.

Comment: The two functions don't have the same behavior, it's natural that they produce different results. Notably, consider negative input values. Try it with `unsigned int`.

Comment: Also note that the compilers know when the functions do the same thing, so you as a programmer don't have to try to optimize at this level.

Comment: Upvoted because many people think `/ 2` or `% 2` can always be compiled as efficiently `as `>>1`, without realizing the mismatch between arithmetic right shift (floor division, rounds towards -Infinity) and C++ signed division / remainder semantics (truncation towards 0).  If there isn't a canonical Q&A about that already, SO could use one.

Comment: If the compiler could prove (e.g. after inlining) that `val` was non-negative (e.g. after `val &= 0xFFFF`), it could use `sar` or `shr` without extra instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's different assembly because division by 2 of a signed integer number must give a well-defined result (by the standard), even when faced with a negative input. The assembly has to account for that, and cannot just do a shift which may produce something "unexpected".

When you write an explicit shift, you acknowledge the looser contract the standard imposes on that operator. So the compiler has more leeway.

Comment: In ISO C++ it's a "looser contract" (i.e. "implementation defined").  In all real implementations of C++ that people actually use, signed right shift uses an arithmetic shift which is fully defined as rounding towards -Infinity (i.e. floor division).  Related: [Python's integer division is floor-division](http://python-history.blogspot.ca/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html), so `x//y` can't just use `idiv` if compiling Python to x86 asm; it has to do something with the sign of a non-zero remainder to correct for off-by-one, similar to what C++ compilers do for `/ 2`.

Comment: @storyteller that makes sense. Could you also explain what these two lines:

 shr eax, 31
 lea eax, [rax + rdi]

are doing extra in your answer, and then I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @skgbanga - You are gonna have to wait for someone who is more adept with x86_64 asm to tell you what those ops do. I'm afraid I'm perplexed myself at the `lea` instruction. All I can tell you is that the net result for signed division must be truncated and with the same sign as the function parameter.

Comment: @StoryTeller Right. While writing the reply to you, I think I understood what is happening. 

After `shr eax, 31` eax contains either 1 or 0 (depending upon whether it is negative or positive). The first 32 bits of `rax` are all 0s or 1s. Now, `lea` adds rax (which is 32 1s/0s followed by 31 0's followed by 1/0) to original argument (present in rdi) and loads the address to eax, after which it can be shifted safely.

Comment: @skgbanga `shr eax,31` will zero-extend result to `rax`, so the `rax` will be `0` or `1` (64b value). It's turning 32b `eax` input integer value into 64b 0/1 value according to it's sign (0 = non-negative value, 1 = negative value). And the `lea` is `eax = rdi_aka_val + ((val < 0) ? 1 : 0)` => negative `val` will be incremented by 1 before shift. That's enough to produce same results as integer signed division by two. (-1+1=0 -> 0>>1=0, -2+1=-1 -> -1>>1=-1  for -1/2 and -2/2).

Comment: Relying on an implementation rather than understanding what implementation defined means is very bad.  Its the works on my machine problem rather than I know how to write correct/portable code.  This is becoming more and more of a problem lately as folks have less and less compiler and platform experience.  The two lines of code are not functionally the same per the language thus the difference as pointed out by this answer.